# Sending Devise inevitable to staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have the devise_invitable gem and it works great because I don't want anybody to be able to sign up for the app I developing. When I go to rails console I send the invite `User.invite(.....` everything works great and it sends the email but only for localhost:3000. I want to send it to my heroku staging server. Any ideas on what I may be missing? Please let me know if you need to see code, I'm just not sure what to post right now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply `heroku run rails console`